# 4-SAT but two literals per clause must be true

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, satisfiability, 3-sat

I'm trying to show that a modified 4-SAT in which at least two literals per clause must be true is NP-complete. I'll call it $4_2$-SAT. I understand the reduction from 3-SAT to 4-SAT, and I know why $4_2$-SAT is in the class NP, so I'm just struggling on the reduction from 4-SAT to $4_2$-SAT (or any other way to show that $4_2$-SAT is NP-hard).

My initial attempt was to try and convert an instance of 4-SAT

$(a \vee b \vee c \vee d)$

into an instance of $4_2$-SAT by spelling out the requirement as

$(a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge d) \vee (b \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge d) \vee (c \wedge d)$

and then convert to CNF and add extra literals if needed to get to four per clause, but this conversion does not preserve the answer of the original 4-SAT clause.

Any hints or help as to how to convert an instance of 4-SAT into $4_2$-SAT would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help, but one way to do this is to go through all possible combinations of assigning two literals true.  i.e. let $T(x_1,x_2) = (x_1 \land x_2)$.  Then your clause becomes $T(a,b) \lor T(a,c) \lor T(a,d) \lor T(b,c) \lor T(b,d) \lor T(c,d)$.  You should be able to reduce 6-SAT to this by expanding all 2-tuple combinations into 6-tuples.  For instance, $(a \land b) \lor (c \land d)$ becomes $(a \lor c) \land (a \lor d) \land (b \lor c) \land (b \lor d)$.  To see this more clear, repalce $\lor$ symbols with $+$ and $\land$ symbols with $*$.

Answer (score 3):

[Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem) settles the complexity of your problem.

Consider a constraint satisfaction problem (CSP) in which there is a finite collections $S$ of types of constraints over Boolean variables, and an instance is a conjunction of constraints of the form $R(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k)$, where $R \in S$ is a $k$-ary constraint and $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k$ are arbitrary literals; the goal is to determine whether the instance is satisfiable, that is, whether there is a truth assignment to the variables which satisfies all constraints. For example, 3SAT is the case in which $S$ consists of the constraint $x \lor y \lor z$, and in your problem $S$ consists of the constraint $R_{4,2}$ "at least two out of $x,y,z,w$ are true".

- If each $R \in S$ is equivalent to a 2CNF, then the CSP can be solved in polynomial time by reduction to 2SAT. This condition holds iff the set of satisfying assignments of each $R \in S$ is closed under *ternary majority*: if $R$ is a $k$-ary constraint, then for any three satisfying assignments $a,b,c$, the assignment $\operatorname{maj}(a_1,b_1,c_1),\ldots,\operatorname{maj}(a_k,b_k,c_k)$ also satisfies $R$.
- If each $R \in S$ is equivalent to a conjunction of linear equations, then the CSP can be solved in polynomial time using Gaussian elimination. This condition holds iff the set of satisfying assignments of each $R \in S$ is closed under *ternary XOR*: if $R$ is a $k$-ary constraint, then for any three satisfying assignments $a,b,c$, the assignment $a_1 \oplus b_1 \oplus c_1,\ldots,a_k \oplus b_k \oplus c_k$ also satisfies $R$.
- In all other cases, the CSP is NP-complete.

In your case, you can check that $R_{4,2}$ is not closed under the two operations above:

- The truth assignments $(1,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0),(1,0,0,1)$ satisfy $R_{4,2}$, but their majority $(1,0,0,0)$ doesn't.
- The truth assignments $(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1),(1,1,1,1)$ satisfy $R_{4,2}$, but their XOR $(0,0,0,0)$ doesn't.

Therefore your problem is NP-complete.

The proof of Schaefer's theorem gives a gadget reduction from either 3SAT or 3NAE-SAT to any NP-complete CSP (3NAE-SAT only occurs if the set of solutions of each $R$ is closed under complementation, which is not the case for $R_{4,2}$), but this reduction is rather verbose.

In your case, here is a simple reduction from 3SAT to your problem: replace each clause $a \lor b \lor c$ with the constraint $R_{4,2}(a,b,c,d)$, where $d$ is a new variable common to all clauses (alternatively, you can make $d$ a new variable for each clause, which would make it a gadget reduction in the sense of Schaefer's theorem).